# Secure files with app pool identity

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have an ASP MVC application installed on IIS 7.5.

I have specified the app pool identity to be a domain service account.

The application has anonymous authentication disabled and windows authentication enabled.
The domain service account has full access to a set of files on the server that  I want to access from ASP.

When I try and access the files from the ASP application I get an error, "access to the path ... is denied.".

I can only get this to go away by giving the windows user account access to the files. What I want to do is just give the service account access to the files.

Impersonation is disabled in the web.config via `<identity impersonate="false" />`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling [ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that impersonation is disabled

Comment: That should run your code as the domain user. Perhaps specific login types are required (like login as service, or group memberships). What if you impersonate a specific identity?

Comment: it should .. but it doesn't :(

Comment: I would debug this further using the security log and Process Monitor, to see what credentials are used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access files locally on the server, try to use the LocalSystem account for your app-pool identity.